# UIImageView not centered after rotation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation

I manually add an UIImageView to my UIView and center it, this works fine, but after rotating the device, the UIImageView isn't centered anymore (it's moved to the lower left). How can I fix this?

```
logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wi-fi-sticker.png"]];
logoView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:logoView];
```

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: I've got this same problem now, did you fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find any fix, so I locked the screen.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to center mine correctly every time using something like this

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration:{
       CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
       float pos_y, pos_x;
       pos_y = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) ? screen.size.width/2  : screen.size.height/2;
       pos_x = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) ? screen.size.height/2 : screen.size.width/2;

       myImageView.center = CGPointMake(pos_x, pos_y);
}
```

Comment: You can just use "toInterfaceOrientation" instead of [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]".